# LAN9514 Remote-RS485

Tags: usb, ethernet, serialport

i am looking at a way of providing "Remote-RS485" to a common PC-system.

**Currently my plan is:**

Connect one of these [LAN9514](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/00002306A.pdf) via Ethernet to the Host -> USB/UART converter per downstream-> UART/RS485 converter.

**My understanding is:**

On common OS (Windows/Linux) i get - sort of a "plug-and-play" - four "SerialPorts" in my device-tree.

**My Questions are:**

1. Is it "plug-and-play" asuming correct Schematic and Layout, or are there issues with drivers and custom configuration to get a basic system running?
2. What is the EEprom required for? My understanding is, that it stores custom MAC-Addresses, ASIC-Config, Power-Config, USB-IDs and so on. So it is required for ettings retention between Power-Cycles.
3. How would one access the Serial-Ports via Software (E.g C# on Windows or C++ on Linux)? Are these Ports "Just conventional Serial-ports"?
4. If you have used this part before: How is the general expierence? (Drivers, Documentation, Config-Software, Ease of design, ease of integration, etc... ) I know that this is subjective: But it is an important part in settling for a specific device in my opinion.
5. Is there a simpler way to form Ethernet->4x RS485 Serial-Ports (E.g. without the USB/UART converters)?

Comment: You have to store the baudrate somewhere. And possibly other UART communication settings for dinosaur compatibility: data bits, parity, stop bits, handshaking. And for application tier RS485 protocols like Profibus, you also have to set node id somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're completely misinterpreting what this device does. It's a a USB hub - it doesn't work without a USB-host attached – and on that hub, there's also a USB network card. That network card also doesn't work without a USB host attached.

Also, you can't just plug in a USB-serial adapter to one of the downstream ports. All this is, is a hub – you need something to be on the upstream port to actually use the things attached to the downstream ports.

So, the IC you bought needs to be directly, via USB, connected to your controlling PC. You cannot "connect" it via Ethernet - It's not a standalone network device.

So your 1. questions  is a "no, not in the way you think".

Your 2. question is "re-read the datasheet knowing that this is a USB hub with a USB network card attached", the Datasheet actually has tables of what this EEPROM is used for.

Your 3. question is "not at all".

Your 4. question is "nobody has used this part in your configuration, because that configuration isn't how USB works, at all".

Your 5. question is "Yes. You just need a minimalist computer with a serial port and an ethernet interface". Something like a Raspberry Pi (which I don't like very much), any other Single-board-Computer with ethernet, or one of these [Microchip Linux-Capable System-on-Modules](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/SAM9X60D1G-I/LZB), maybe. Honestly, any microcontroller eval board that brings an ethernet PHY, if you don't need incredible speeds on your RS485, but you'd have to build your own firmware. Sometimes, just dropping in an embedded Linux device somewhere is much easier.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is a "great" Info ;) You saved me a lot of head-scratching ;)

Comment: Do you happen to know a device which could accomplisch my requirements? So PC<->Ethernet<->min. Four USB2.0 as ASIC.

Comment: Why USB2.0? You never mentioned that requirement – you said RS485, and that has literally nothing to do with USB.

Comment: You are correct - sorry. If you  know a Ethernet<->RS485 ASIC even better. I guessed my chances for an Ethernet<->USB<->UART<->RS485 system are higher.

Comment: Why do you need to design it? Ethernet to RS-485 boxes already exist. What exactly you want to do, control an RS-485 device via Ethernet, or the other way around?

Comment: @ElectronicsStudent I answered that already in my answer. Last paragraph.

Comment: and, no, adding USB to the mix here makes everything more complex, not easier.